# Mule: Is it possible to store objects in a sequence in Mule Object Store?

Tags: object, mule

I have a requirement where I need to store incoming data (which is in JSON format) in a sequence for retrieval later in the following manner:

1  | JSONData1
2  | JSONData2
3  | JSONData3
...
N  | JSONDataN

The reason for this is if a failure occurs in processing at number 3 , I can feed in the value 3  retrieve the JSON data and continue processing from that point to the next record till the last available record.

Now Mule Object Store has behavior like a Hash, where no ordering is maintained as far as I know. So do I have to fall back on Java provided data structures for maintaining the ordering & retrieval or is there a way I can still leverage the Object Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable with `java.util.Hashmap` and use that variable while storing json data into Object Store.
Each time the json data is stored you can increment the variable with 1, so it will store the json data in sequence tracking each data like 1, 2, 3.
Here you can get the example  http://bushorn.com/dealing-with-store-the-object-store/